# How to pass React state to multiple pages and components with Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-state, react-state-management, reactive-variable

I have some simple state defined using React `useState`:

`const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState(true);`

Then in a component I show or hide the banner:

`{showBanner && <Banner onClick={() => setShowBanner(false)} />}`

I need to pass this state to multiple pages and components. How can I do that with Apollo Client? Would using [Reactive variables](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/) be an option?

Comment: Why would you use Apollo Client for that? Why not a simple `Context` (or some other React state management solution)?

Comment: I thought Apollo Clients state management features are more easy (and less code) to implement?